# JSON response dump first record of the array

Tags: php, json

I have a webservice name `geteventsPost.php`
which is basic code to return data in JSON format

I tried to debug in browser tools, from which it seems like in that variable `event` there is always one record short.
Very first record of the query gets dumped
Here is my `JSON` webservice code
I tried to see the response in web browser it look like it returns one record short.

```
<?php
include 'dbconnection.php';


/*
 * Following code will list all the products
 */

// array for JSON response
$response = array();

if(isset ($_GET['id'])) {
// get all products from products table
try {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM event where organiser_id =".$_GET['id'];
    $result = $pdo->query($sql);
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
    echo 'Error fetching data: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit();
}

}


// check for empty result
if ($result->fetch() > 0) {
// looping through all results
// master menu node
$response["event"] = array();

while ($row = $result->fetch()) {
    // temp user array
    $event= array();
    $event["id"] = $row["id"];
    $event["title"] = $row["title"];
    $event["location"] = $row["location"];
    $event["start_date"] = $row["start_date"];


    // push single menu into final response array
    array_push($response["event"], $event);
}
// success
$response["success"] = 1;

// echoing JSON response
echo json_encode($response);
} else {
// no products found
$response["success"] = 0;
$response["message"] = "No event found";

// echo no users JSON
echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

So i just want to know that what am i doing wrong?
I am guessing its in the script code some where i am handling the response wrong.

Let me know 
thank you

Comment: and what is the result of the json?

Comment: @RedAcid i solved it using the answer below.. It was issue with `$result` i was handling it wrong.. thank you anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out:

```
if ($result->rowCount() > 0) {
$response = array();
    while ($row = $result->fetch()) {
        $response["event"][] = $row; 
    }
$response["success"] = 1;
echo json_encode($response);
}
```

I don't know more about how you are handling the json but you should add that if this doesn't answer your question.

Comment: thank you.. i got it.. it was the issue with the `$result->fetch()`, it should be `$result->rowCount() > 0` solved the problem...